# How to show that $(H,\cdot)$ is normal subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $H=\left\{\left( \begin{matrix} a&b   \\0&d\end{matrix} \right) :a,b,d\in \Bbb R \text{ and } ad\neq 0\right\}$. Show that $(H,\cdot)$ is a normal subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb R)$.

Is this a correct statement? I mean $\left( \begin{matrix} 2&1   \\1&1\end{matrix} \right) \in GL_2(\Bbb R)$ and in order to have

$$\left(\begin{matrix} 2&1   \\1&1\end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix} a&b   \\0&d\end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1   \\-1&2\end{matrix} \right)\in H$$ shouldn't it satisfy $a-b-d=0$ so $a=b+d$?

Comment: I think that it is not true.

Comment: It's definitely _not_ a normal subgroup.

Comment: Usually the exercise is to show that $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a normal subgroup.