# Show that $T$ is normal in $GL_{2}(\Bbb{R})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Show that $T=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
> a &b \\ 
> 0 & c
> \end{bmatrix}:a,b,c\in \Bbb{R}, ac\neq 0 \right \}$ is normal in $GL_{2}(\Bbb{R})$.

I don't think it is normal, because for any arbitrary matrix $a\in GL_{2}(\Bbb{R})$ and $t\in T$, $ata^{-1}\notin T$. Is this a valid argument?

Comment: This is not true for any matrix $a$ (a bad name for a matrix) but you only need one example of $a$ and $t$ with $ata^{-1}$ to refute normality.

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601557/how-to-show-that-h-cdot-is-normal-subgroup-of-gl-2-bbb-r?rq=1). See the answer in the comment.

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282401/prove-that-this-subgroup-is-normal-in-g-where-g-is-a-subgroup-of-gl2-bbb?rq=1) was meant by the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for taking the time to find these answers. May I ask how you found them? I cannot search for answers properly for some reason.

Comment: I found them under "Related", see the right margin.